# Auto linking domain account to live IDs

Tags: windows-8.1

There's any way to link domain account to live ID?

I've seen that when you link domain account to live ID, in registry this keys are generated:

```
[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\StoredIdentities\myliveIDaccount@outlook.com]
"Keywords"="Associated"
"CID"="6213e28fcbefc3ed"
"AssociatedCount"=dword:00000001
"AccountsCount"=dword:00000002
"LatestDPAPIKeyVersion"="1387274538"

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\StoredIdentities\myliveIDaccount@outlook.com\S-1-5-21-95946...]
"AccountType"="DomainConnected"
"Flags"="40000643"
"FirstName"="my"
"DisplayName"="id account"
"LastName"="test"
"Keywords"="Associated;Connected"
"LatestDPAPIKeyVersion"="1387274538"
"ChildFlags"="00000001"
"DefaultCredSaved"="Persisted"
```

If i import that keys to another PC, everything is working fine: domain account is linked to live ID and i can access to Store.

But, if i import that keys to another PC with "LatestDPAPIKeyVersion" and "CID" modified, the domain account seems to be linked to live ID but i have seen two differents behaviors:

- First time, i couldn't enter the Store. It was stuck on the green screen, loading the store for more then 30 minutes.
- Second time, i entered the Store, but when I tried to download app it asked me the password

So here comes the final cuestion:

Knowing all that, is there a way to link domain accounts to live ID accounts in an automatic way, assuming we know the live ID accounts and their password?

Thanks!